# Sort Parent rows based on a child property in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I'm using hibernate criteria to sort parent rows based on date property of child collections

```java
public class Parent
{
   private int id;    
   private string code;    

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
   private Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<>(0);
}
    
public class Child
{
   private int id;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)  
   private Date startDate;    

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
   private Parent parent;
}
```

```java
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
cr.createAlias("parent.childs", "childs");
cr.addOrder(Order.desc("childs.startDate"));
cr.setFirstResult(0);
cr.setMaxResults(20);                
cr.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
(List<Parent>)cr.list();
```

Though there are 20 parent records list is returning 13 records

Comment: That shouldn't work at all as `Set` has not property with the name `startDate`

Comment: @Nikilesh What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK version is 4.3.6